# Parse Crash Reporting Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, crash-reports, run-script

I've been following this tutorial on how to enable Parse Crash Reporting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4SMyHAVJgk

However, after I create the run script and build my app, I get the following error: `/bin/sh failed with exit code 2`

I'm not the best at understanding weird error codes like this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my run script:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd </Users/dom/MyApp/parse>

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Also, I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: mine fails with exit code 1, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "<>" so let it just:

```
cd /Users/dom/MyApp/parse
```

Comment: No problem! We all have those moments where the solution is just in front of our eyes but we still don't see it, have a good one!