# Parse Crash Reporting: Do Not Understand Symbol Files at:

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, crash-reports

I think I spent a whole day on this and still don't have a clue what the issue is.

The error I get every time the project builds is "Do not understand symbol files at :/Users/natecraft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingCrashes-dytajkglkhaghgficdgpolnmndnr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestingCrashes.app.dSYM"

Following the crash guide [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#crash-reporting) , I manually uploaded the dSYM file with this... parse symbols  --path="" which I believe worked. How do I verify?  I saw this in the docs "If you set up automatic uploading, verify that the uploads have worked by looking at the logs under the Report navigator." But can't find the "Report Navigator".

I've tried many variations of the actual Run Script, most recently from this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147300/xcode-parse-crash-reporting-dsym-file-not-created). But nothing has made a difference. The only thing I can think of that's different with my sample TestingCrashes project and the Parse guides i'm following is that I'm using CocoaPods, and XCode 7.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-check in your Build Settings that your Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release